# Facebook event create crashes when tested in mobile

Tags: android, facebook, emulation

I have the following code to create an event on facebook. It works fine on the emulator but crashes in the phone (Sony Miro):

```
 private void createEvents()
        {
            try
            {

                mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
                String accessToken = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
                facebookatEventCreate.setAccessToken(accessToken);
                long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);

                if (accessToken != null)
                {
                    facebookatEventCreate.setAccessToken(accessToken);
                }

                if (expires != 0)
                {
                    facebookatEventCreate.setAccessExpires(expires);
                }

                if (!facebookatEventCreate.isSessionValid())
                {
                    facebookatEventCreate.authorize(this, new String[] {
                        "email", "publish_stream", "create_event"
                    }, new DialogListener()
                    {

                        @Override
                        public void onCancel()
                        {
                            // Function to handle cancel event
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(Bundle values)
                        {
                            // Function to handle complete event
                            // Edit Preferences and update facebook acess_token
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                            editor.putString("access_token", facebookatEventCreate.getAccessToken());
                            editor.putLong("access_expires", facebookatEventCreate.getAccessExpires());
                            editor.commit();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(DialogError error)
                        {
                            // Function to handle error

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError fberror)
                        {
                            // Function to handle Facebook errors

                        }

                    });
                }



                //getting the event name from the text box
                String eventName = txtEventName.getText().toString();
                Log.d("createEvent:createEvent", "Event Name->"+ eventName);

                //getting the event location from the text box
                String eventLocation = txtEventLocation.getText().toString();
                Log.d("createEvent:createEvents", "Event Location->"+ eventLocation);

                //getting the event description from the text box
                String eventDescription = txtEventDescription.getText().toString();
                Log.d("createEvent:createEvents", "Event Description->"+eventDescription);               


                //this is the date of the event picked from the dialog
                //Log.d("createEvent:createEvents", "new Time->" + startDate);
                startDateAndTime = startDate + startTime;
                Log.d("createEvent:createEvents", "DATE AND TIME->"+startDateAndTime);



                Bundle params = new Bundle();
                params.putString("name", eventName);
                params.putString("start_time", startDateAndTime);
                //params.putString("end_time", "2013-12-02T20:00:00+0530");
                params.putString("description", eventDescription);
                params.putString("location", eventLocation);
                params.putString("privacy_type", "OPEN");

                mAsyncRunner1.request("me/events", params, "POST", new RequestListener()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e, Object state)
                    {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state)
                    {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e, Object state)
                    {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state)
                    {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(String response, Object state)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            JSONObject event = new JSONObject(response);
                            eventID = event.getString("id");
                            Log.d("createEvent:createEvent", "Event ID->" + eventID);
                            Log.i(response, response);

                           //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "New Event Created!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {

                        }
                    }
                }, null);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
        }
```

I get following messages on logcat that I never saw when debugging with the emulator:

```
12-13 11:26:01.019: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(6360): <ConfigWindowMatch:2081>: Format RGBA_8888.
12-13 11:26:01.029: D/memalloc(6360): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x51832000 size:614400 offset:0 fd:67
12-13 11:26:01.179: D/memalloc(6360): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x51b51000 size:2396160 offset:1781760 fd:70
12-13 11:26:02.259: D/memalloc(6360): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x51e9a000 size:3010560 offset:2396160 fd:73
12-13 11:26:02.399: D/-heap(6360): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 125K, 16% free 6562K/7775K, paused 21ms
12-13 11:26:02.499: D/-heap(6360): GC_CONCURRENT freed 3K, 8% free 15558K/16803K, paused 2ms+2ms
```

And this:

```
12-13 11:26:17.899: E/ActivityThread(6360): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider
```

With this the app crashes:

```
12-13 11:26:18.979: V/WebRequest(6360): WebRequest::WebRequest, setPriority = 1
12-13 11:26:19.159: E/WindowManager(6360): Activity com.hsenid.eventer.ui.createEvent has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41b70728 that was originally added here
12-13 11:26:19.159: E/WindowManager(6360): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.hsenid.eventer.ui.createEvent has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41b70728 that was originally added here
12-13 11:26:19.159: E/WindowManager(6360):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:345)
12-13 11:26:19.159: E/WindowManager(6360):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:268)
12-13 11:26:19.159: E/WindowManager(6360):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:216)
12-13 11:26:19.159: E/WindowManager(6360):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:141)
12-13 11:26:19.159: E/WindowManager(6360):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537)
```

Please let me know what I should do...Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

try to use strict mode

`StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
    .permitAll().build();
  StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);`

if that doesent work in your manifest file change

```
android:minSdkVersion="yourminumsdkhere"
    android:targetSdkVersion="yourmaximumsdkhere"
```

to `android:minSdkVersion="yourminumsdkhere"
        android:targetSdkVersion="yourminumsdkhere"`

i think StrictMode will help you. and also one more suggetion are you using multiple windows pop up during the network operation .it may also lead to the crash as shown in the log cat.
thank you